# Use definite article or not in conjunction with a German institution's name which contains a strongly declined article?

Tags: articles, non-native-english, german

Picture some German university's arthistory department, and its official title would be "Kunsthistorisches Institut". "Kunsthistorisch" is an adjective, and "kunsthistorisches" is its nominative case. Moreover, "kunsthistorisches" is the strong declension case which is used without a definite article.

Now when I'd like to refer to said department's bibliography rules in an English text, I would have to use the definite article "the", which would be at odds with the strong declension in the institution's German name.

Still, what would be the correct alternative,

- "...the bibliography rules of the 'Kunsthistorisches Institut'..." or
- "...the bibliography rules of 'Kunsthistorisches Institut'...",

or would I even have to adapt to the appropriate German declension case (genitive or dative)? (My instinct makes me shudder.)

Comment: Patterning on British examples such as 'the Blind Institute', I'd add the article. 'Kunsthistorisches Institut' has been adopted into English in your English text.

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth, but the completely analogous case to 'Kunsthistorisches Institut' would be '_a_ Blind Institute', not 'the' - yet I have to use the definite article here. The grammatical logic of both languages is at odds here (and both alternatives sound odd to my ears).
Is there a general rule that says that grammatical rules of foreign language expressions can be neglected entirely when such expressions are being adopted?

Comment: Whether there's a general rule or not, which will sound correct to your audience?  If 90% of your audience does not understand German, then there's your answer.

Comment: See also [Should foreign words be inflected?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/351980/should-foreign-words-used-in-english-be-inflected-for-gender-number-and-case-a)

Comment: Thank you @Mitch, an interesting read, and clearly related. Yet I have the strong feeling that I can't meddle with the German word's declension (because it's an official name), so I'll have to decide whether or not to use "the" or not.

Comment: @JohnFeltz I believe my audience will rather be 90% Germans, yet both alternatives sound bad to a German ear, so that line of reasoning won't help me much.

Comment: @Turtle Well that's unfortunate.  Turn it around and use the 's possessive instead?  "Kunsthistorisches Institut's bibliographical rules..."  You're going to have to break something somewhere.

Comment: "the completely analogous case to 'Kunsthistorisches Institut' would be 'a Blind Institute' " is only true if you are basing the analogy solely on the semantics and grammar of the source language and a requirement to reflect this in the target language. I'm basing the analogy on apparent form, essentially adopting  'Kunsthistorisches Institut' as a title, a proper noun (as Rowling does with 'He Who Must Not Be Named', using say 'to He Who Must Not Be Named' rather than 'to Him ...').

Comment: Are you talking about the one at [Universität Wien](http://kunstgeschichte.univie.ac.at/)? Or the one in [Florenz](http://www.khi.fi.it/2169/en)? Another one? (Does it matter?)

Comment: @JohnFeltz I like your idea, but because the institute is being introduced in the same sentence, my feeling is I should use an "of" construction.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you persuaded me that your suggestion is ultimately the best, and your Voldemort example certainly helped. (Maybe a combination of your comments would be nice answer?)

Comment: As a German, I would use “the Kunsthistorische Institut”, regardless of the case.

Comment: @Carsten S Yes, a better Anglicisation without the 's'. See you for football at Christmas :)

Answer (score 1):

In English, names headed by *institute* nearly always take "the"; hence my hometown has "the Kalamazoo Institute of Arts", "the Haenicke Institute for Global Education", etc.

Now, that's not a general rule for all nouns — for example, names headed by *academy*, *college*, and *university* can go either way — but German *Institut* is so close to English *institute* (and is likely to be pronounced simply as "institute" by English-speakers) that I think it sounds very odd without "the".

That said, since in your case the German name is very transparent (not very namelike), and it's not a top-level organization but is rather just a department of a larger one, I would suggest translating the name, and writing "the Art History Institute" (unless this department is already known in English under its German name, in which case you should look at existing usage to see whether it has "the").

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to dodge the problem by translating the whole name into English.  Notice also that you can then append the German name parenthetically without worrying about articles: The Art History Institute (Kunsthistorisches Institut).  You could also use "Department" instead of "Institute" in the English version, if that more accurately describes the place of this department/institute in the university.